# How to characterize scalars making the scalar multiplication surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a unital commutative ring and let $A$ be a right $R$-module. For each $u\in R$, let $f_u:A\to A,\ a\mapsto au$. Is there a nice way to characterize $u\in R$ making $f_u$ surjective?

My work so far. Define sets as follows:

1. $R^\times$ is the set of all units in $R$;
2. $S=\{u\in R:\text{$f_u$ is surjective}\}$;
3. $T=\{u\in R:\text{For all $v\in R$, if $uv=0$ then $f_v=0$}\}$.

I proved that $R^\times\subseteq S\subseteq T$. These sets might or might not be relevant.

Comment: I don't believe there's any other interesting characterization. The inclusion $R^{\times}\subseteq S$ certainly need not be an equality.

Comment: I've heard of the "injective" version of this but not the "surjective" version. Interesting.

Comment: @rschwieb Are there results for injective version?

Comment: @zxcv I mean, that just says that $a$ is a regular element (at least, not a left zero divisor.)